# How select an element button by title and hide it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following button on a page, all I want is be able to select it via title or any other property and hide it.

```
<button title="Show all journal fields" type="button" class="icon-stream-all-input btn-default btn" ng-click="toggleMultipleInputs(true)"> <span class="sr-only"> Show all journal fields </span></button>
```

Comment: Well then go look up CSS attribute selectors.

Comment: `$("button [title='Show all journal fields']").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

**css approach**

```css
button[title="Show all journal fields"]{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<button title="Show all journal fields" type="button" class="icon-stream-all-input btn-default btn" ng-click="toggleMultipleInputs(true)"> <span class="sr-only"> Show all journal fields </span></button>
```

**Javascript approach**

```js
document.querySelector("button[title='Show all journal fields']").style.display="none";
```

```html
<button title="Show all journal fields" type="button" class="icon-stream-all-input btn-default btn" ng-click="toggleMultipleInputs(true)"> <span class="sr-only"> Show all journal fields </span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector for the title attribute:

```
var titleSearchStr = 'Show all journal fields';
var items = $('[title="'+ titleSearchStr +'"]');
items.hide();
```